# need help to convert my java project for working in the office

Tags: java, database, user-interface, deployment, installation

I have created a Java project.  Now I want to give it to the office as an .exe or something similar, to allow them to use it without installing any Java IDE.  What should i do?  My project contains a database and GUI.

Comment: you will need to create an executable jar (basically the same as an exe but for java) which will run on any system with the required jre version.  You may also need to create some form of executable which could install the jre and all relevant databases etc, or get your java program to create its relevant databses/directories etc.

Comment: What IDE do you use?  Probably the IDE already does most of the work of preparing the executable code for you.

Comment: i use eclipse ide (indigo version)

Comment: In the Eclipse help, look up "Runnable JAR File Exporter".

Comment: okey let me clear. i want to give a project which contains gui and database to a office . there a employee will run this program for the purpose of storing customer's id and there details.he is not going to know the java programming .so i need to give him something so that he can just double-click the program and run it.

Comment: A bit suppose status is 1 then i want to relate it with a table and if the status is 0 then i want to relate it with another table,how can i do that? 
Be more specific,suppose in a table there is a column name marital_status which takes 1 if married and 0 if not.I want to relate it with another table name married_people table if status is 1 and if status is 0 i want to relate it with another table unmarried_people table.Please tell me how will i do that in database.

Comment: i cannot post this quesion becoz they found that my question there is a problem .can anyone re-post it and send me the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should i do? My project contains a database and GUI.

Deploy the app. and database using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  For installing the DB, it would be necessary to use the `ExtensionInstallerService` (see a [demo. of the EIS](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis)).  Configuration for the DB can be stored using the `PersistenceService` ([demo. of the PS](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps)).

See also references to the `deployJava.js` in the 1st linked page.  It aims to ensure the end user has the right minimum Java needed to run the app.